# no grain for good diet

Tags: diet

I have read several books advising a no grain diet. The main argument in favor of this approach is that the human body is not meant to digest grains: people started to consume grains around 10000 years ago - it is too short a period for evolution to come into action and our body are still unable to properly digest grains.

I wanted to know if there were any scientific study advising this "no grain" approach to good health ?

Comment: Sounds like a founding argument of the Paleo diet.  Have you looked into this?

Comment: **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nutrition** Read these will answer your question and make you feel better

Comment: Are these books by [Joseph Mercola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Mercola)?

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the standard low-carb movement, the primary basis for this position is the lectins that are found in grains. Grain lectins are thought to be mildly toxic.

Certain carbohydrates seem to protect the body from some of these lectins (e.g. glucosamine protects against wheat lectins), but are not always 100% effective.

For more, see [this article](http://www.krispin.com/lectin.html) about lectins, which contains an in-depth explanation and references to source research papers.